# Custom Intl.Collator in JS

Tags: javascript, sorting, string-comparison, collator

I need to sort this array

```
['$', 'z', 7, 'a', 1, '%', '.', 5, '% hello', ' ', 'f', '^' , '-', '_']
```

as

```
[ , %, % hello, _, -, ., ^, $, 1, 5, 7, a, f, z]
```

But the result I'm getting is

```
[ , _, -, ., %, % hello, ^, $, 1, 5, 7, a, f, z]
```

Is there any way to create custom collator? In this case, is it possible to get the position of any specific character or symbol say '%' before other symbols?

```js
 var collator = Intl.Collator();
var letters = ['$', 'z', 7, 'a', 1, '%', '.', 5, '% hello', ' ', 'f', '^' , '-', '_'];
console.log(letters.sort(collator.compare));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Could you try this I am not sure If that is completed solution for your issue or not**

```
var collator = Intl.Collator();
        var letters = ['$', 'z', 7, 'a', 1, '%', '.', 5, '% hello', ' ', 'f', '^', '-', '_'];
        arr = letters.sort(collator.compare);
        arr.forEach((item, index) => {
            if (String(item).indexOf('%') >= 0) {
                arr.splice(0, index + 1, ...arr.slice(0, index + 1).sort())
            }
        });
        console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a custom sorting by specifying letters to be sorted first.

This approach takes a sorting with map where each items is mapped to the following array and then all items are mapped by the order of the sorted indices.

```
[
    {
        index: 5,
        value: "%"
    },
    {
        index: 8,
        value: "% hello"
    },
    {
        index: 0,
        value: "$"
    },
    {
        index: 9,
        value: " "
    },
    {
        index: 13,
        value: "_"
    },
    {
        index: 12,
        value: "-"
    },
    {
        index: 6,
        value: "."
    },
    {
        index: 11,
        value: "^"
    },
    {
        index: 4,
        value: "1"
    },
    {
        index: 7,
        value: "5"
    },
    {
        index: 2,
        value: "7"
    },
    {
        index: 3,
        value: "a"
    },
    {
        index: 10,
        value: "f"
    },
    {
        index: 1,
        value: "z"
    }
]
```

```js
var array = ['$', 'z', 7, 'a', 1, '%', '.', 5, '% hello', ' ', 'f', '^', '-', '_'],
    first = '%$ ', // take % first, then $ then space then rest by standard sorting
    check = [...first, ''],
    result = array
        .map((item, index) => {
            var value = '';
            for (let c of [...item.toString()]) {
                value += check
                    .map(v => !check.includes(c) && !v || v === c ? c : '\uFFFF')
                    .join('');
            }
            return { index, value };
        })
        .sort((a, b) => a.value.localeCompare(b.value))
        .map(({ index }) => array[index]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep an array of `order` you want and then sort as following

```js
let Order = { ' ': 1, '%': 2, '_': 4, '-': 5, '.': 6, '^': 7, '$': 8 }

let array = ['$', 'z', 7, 'a', 1, '%', '.', 5, '% hello', ' ', 'f', '^', '-', '_'];

array.sort((a, b) => {
 if (Order[a] && Order[b]) {
  return Order[a] - Order[b];
 } else {
  let x = [...a.toString()].find(e => Order[e]);
  let y = [...b.toString()].find(e => Order[e]);
  if (Order[x] && Order[y])
   return (Order[x]) - (Order[y]);
  return a.toString().localeCompare(b)
 }
});
console.log(array)
```