# What is the Javascript locale equivelant to `Array.prototype.sort`?

Tags: javascript, locale

Javascript's string comparisons and Array.prototype.sort compares strings unicode code points character by character.

`String.prototype.localeCompare` and `Intl.Collator.prototype.compare` both compare strings using locale aware rules. These methods implement the negative, zero, positive interface used by `Array.prototype.sort`, so they are useful for sorting objects by a field

```
// nice!
records.sort((a, b) => a.field.localeCompare(b.field))

// boo
records.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.field === b.field) return 0
  if (a.field < b.field) return -1
  if (a.field > b.field) return 1
})
```

Is there a locale I can pass to localeCompare or Intl.Collator to make it equivalent to string's `>`, `<`, `===`?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, no. Omitting the locale definition means the [default locale](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-initializecollator) is used instead. This however does not match the default string behavior: `['ä', 'a', 'ü', 'u'].sort()` yields a different order than `['ä', 'a', 'ü', 'u'].sort(new Intl.Collator().compare)`. I don't know of a way of [creating a fully custom collator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60704123/1470607) either. You could wrap a collator in a proxy, but that's more code than using a simple function for sorting.